# Small capacitor in series with battery pack - Why/how?

Tags: capacitor, identification

I have a device with a 12V battery pack (it's actually eight AA batteries in a harness.)

In taking it apart, I see that it has a small capacitor in series with the positive side of the supply. So, just a small indistinguishable capacitor between the + terminal of the 12V battery pack and the switch.

I'm seriously questioning myself here.  Why is there a capacitor here? Won't that break the voltage? It's not in parallel, and it's DC.

What am I missing?

Edited to add this picture:
[image: What I believe should be a capacitor, but may not be.]

It's heavily corroded around the leads, the right pole in the image connected to one side of a switch. The left side pokes through that plastic to the positive terminal in the battery harness.

To be honest, there isn't anything more to this circuit on this side. It goes to a motor, that's all. The negative terminal goes directly to the motor.

Since the comments are suggesting this is likely a fuse, that would certainly explain why I have no luck figuring out what kind of capacitor this is. Also explains why this circuit works, since it's not a capacitor.

Comment: There's a fair chance that it's not a capacitor, but something like a self-resetting fuse.  Difficult to tell with no picture or description.  A photo would be best.

Comment: Small Raychem Poly Switches look very much like small radial capacitors.  The Raychem parts are gold / yellow, if that helps.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Thanks for your help. I would never have guessed this wasn't a capacitor.